# What does it mean "it stopped short of overturning the policy"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> But it stopped short of overturning the policy, saying instead that parliament should be given time to legislate on the matter.

Does it mean "it stopped of overturning the policy short". But I can't find a usage like this.

If it means "Short of overturning the policy, it stopped", I think it is unreasonable.

This is an article in *The Economist*.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you stop short of something, you do everything leading up to that thing, but you don't do the thing itself. Here the court said the ban was wrong, but it didn't actually overturn it.

Comment: How do you know this usage? I can't find it in any dictionaries I can refer to.

Comment: See eg [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/short_2#stop_idmg_11) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stop-short-of-sth)